# How to sign in once in an android application?

Tags: android, signing

i'm making an app in android, it has more than one option in the menu, and the login information is needed to proceed in every option, so i want to make the user sign only once not each time he's choosing one of the options like the facebook application i have to sign in only once even when the application is running in the background it doesn't logout.. 
sry 4 the long explanation but i don't know even the keyword for searching about this issue..

can u please help me guys ? 
Thank u

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the user enter the login credential first time then use `SharedPreferences` and set the value to `isLogged` to `1`.

Next time when user open the app then check this variable if this variable value is '1' then open the home activity.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("data",MODE_PRIVATE);
int number = sharedPref.getInt("isLogged", 0);
if(number == 0) {
    //Open the login activity and set this so that next it value is 1 then this conditin will be false.
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
    prefEditor.putInt("isLogged",1);
    prefEditor.commit();
} else {
       //Open this Home activity
}
```

Comment: Can i ask u another quest. 
SO when i need to sign out i'll just use this code or another code should be used ? 

{finish();
System.exit(0);}

Comment: @NaneesNabil When you sign out then set this variable value to 0 again.